# aspx support in browsers running on Linux

Tags: linux, browser

Is there a plugin, configuration, etc. that allows browsers on Linux (Opera, Firefox, Chromium) to fully utilize the capabilities of aspx pages on various websites.

My specific issue is that I can't save a PDF from a (city government) site, I click on it and go through the motions (a file save dialog pops up with the filename, I click save) but nothing happens.  When I called the city they said "Have to use IE" (they know it's brain dead and are working to fix it - but when...).

My web searches for 'aspx linux support' all return entries about delivering aspx pages from a Linux server using mono and asp.net, not browser support.